# The word: обощ, in gen. pl. and nom. pl?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Здравствуйте,

I am trying to figure out the word: "овощ", in genitive pl. and nominative pl., I have tried various other sources but the answers comes back as "Word not found" or something else that is not applicable. Can you please help?

Большое спасибо,

Comment: There's no such word. Could be "овощ", or "общ[ий]", "общ[ество]", or just anything else.

Comment: Neither "обощ", nor "обощи". I really can't guess what you mean. Maybe "обочь" (on the side; cf. "обочина" = "roadside"). Please, provide any relevant context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There well and truly is no such word. I'm guessing it's a misspelling (more of a typo or transliteration accident, really) of **овощ**, which has nom. pl. **óвощи** and gen. pl. **овощéй**.

**UPD.** Oh! Dahl's dictionary actually [does list](http://megabook.ru/article/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%89%20%E2%94%80%20%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%92.%D0%98.%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F) **обощ** it as a southern dialectal form of **овощ**. The endings would be the same (standardly, anyway; the respective dialect *might* have been sufficiently Ukrainian-leaning to go for *обощов* or *обощев*), and with the lot of dialectal levelling-out in the 20th century there's a high chance the form is extinct by now, or else surviving in a handful of villages.

Comment: Большое спасибо!